# Ensuring monitor does not pick up @media query for mobile

Tags: css

I've built a nice template that has four different layouts using @media queries:

850+px width
<850px width
iphone landscape
iphone portrait

It works awesome, until you size your monitor window down to below 480px (iphone landscape) and then it starts picking up the smaller size @media queries.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: It's doing exactly what it's designed to do. Why change it?

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel like it's desirable to display the "iPhone" layout at smaller browser window sizes, as your content has likely been optimized for that layout, HOWEVER, if you really want to prevent this you can play around with the `device-width` property in your `@media` declaration. Something like `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) { ... }` will target device width rather than viewport width. Compare the behavior of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisjlebron/5PNbC/) (viewport width) vs [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisjlebron/ebsYf/) (device width). Play around with the values (change `min` to `max`, change the pixel sizes, etc.) and observe the behavior. Also, don't forget that you can combine `@media` rules, e.g. `@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px) { ... }`. See what works for you.

The problem with this method is that mobile devices come in all shapes and sizes, so you might be serving undesirable styles on a different mobile device (let's just say an Android phone...) that you hadn't planned on. However, depending on your needs, this might not matter to you.

Here is a list of example media queries and sizes to guide you, if you do decide to go this route: `http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/` (sorry for the lack of a working link; apparently I'm not cool enough on StackOverflow to post multiple links yet)...

Comment: I think you're cool enough now! (I believe 10 rep is the requirement)